# Browsing context has been discarded error sending text input inside an iFrame Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

Im trying to enter the username field on a website and I realise it is inside an iframe on the page. The iframe html code and input field html code are as follows:

```
<iframe class="_2_i9tg _2_i9tg" src="https://gateway-members.bet365.com/v1/auth/oauth/authorise?client_id=BDE2D5E4-127D-48D4-A963-BB49DC126BF7&amp;scope=sports%20members&amp;response_type=code&amp;redirect_uri=https://secure.oddschecker.com/mapp/b3/callback&amp;state=dXNlcklEOmExNWM4OTUxLTlkY2EtNDQ5OC1iNDc3LWUxNzVhMDdjODdlNVNFUGRldmljZVR5cGU6d2luZG93c1NFUGFwaVJlcHViOmFwaV9PQ1NFUGRldmljZUlkOmExNWM4OTUxLTlkY2EtNDQ5OC1iNDc3LWUxNzVhMDdjODdlNQ"></iframe>

<input autocomplete="off" class="inputtextbox" id="Username" name="Username" placeholder="Username" type="text" value="">
```

I have attempted to switch to the iframe and input text multiple ways such as

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='_2_i9tg _2_i9tg']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id = 'Username'][@class = 'inputtextbox']"))).send_keys("Username")
```

and

```
my_iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='_2_i9tg _2_i9tg']")))
driver.switch_to.frame(my_iframe)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//@id = 'Username'][@class = 'inputtextbox']"))).send_keys("Username")
```

When I try to run this code i get an error saying:

```
Browsing context has been discarded
```

When I don't try switch frame I cannot locate the input field element.
What am I missing?

Comment: What is the website you are trying to access? Your code looks more or less correct

Comment: The website is https://www.oddschecker.com. The problem occurs when I am trying to log in to a bookmakerds after adding a selection to betslip

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your exact sequence of events and clicks, but when I press login on the website, the login form does not load in a new iframe.

Comment: Sorry let me try to clarify, I'm not attempting to log in to the oddschecker website. If you go to the site and select something and add it to your betslip, you get the option to log in to the bookmaker of your choice eg bet365. This log in form then appears and when I inspect it is in an ifram, I will add screenshot to my original post.

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately the bet slip isn't working for me, so I can't troubleshoot. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in second try. If it doesn't fix it can you provide html code?

```
//*[@id = 'Username'][@class = 'inputtextbox']
```

Comment: This didnt fix, how should I provide html code? Are the lines in my post not sufficient, i'm unsure how to copy the full html code as it only copys the html for the specific elements when I try.

Comment: Nevermind, I can see you attached pictures and everything looks good from the code as far as see. Have you tried adding `my_iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='_2_i9tg _2_i9tg']")` before `driver.switch_to.frame(my_iframe)`

Answer (score 0):

As the element with the element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://gateway-members.bet365.com/v1/auth/oauth/authorise?client_id']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.inputtextbox#Username[name='Username']"))).send_keys("Eglantine46")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://gateway-members.bet365.com/v1/auth/oauth/authorise?client_id')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='inputtextbox' and @id='Username'][@name='Username']"))).send_keys("Eglantine46")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Thanks for response, Ive tried multiple ways but this code still returns the error 'Browsing context has been discarded'